# mypy complains: function type annotation with Type[TypeVar['T', str, date]] and T output: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "date")

Tags: python, generics, typing, mypy

The intention is to overload the function and allow for multiple types of input, with user-defined coherent output.

I thus set a `Type[TypeVar]` of `str` or `datetime.date` (second function argument, with default value`=str`) where the function would output the relevant `TypeVar`.

The following is the basic function (that I would further extend once this version is fixed):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type
from datetime import date, datetime

DateOutType = TypeVar('DateOutType', str, date)

def date2str(t: date, out_format: Type[DateOutType]=Type[str]) -> DateOutType:
    ''' Converts datetime.date to string (YYYY-MM-DD) or datetime.date output.
    '''
    if out_format is str:
        return t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    elif isinstance(t, datetime):
        return t.date()
    else:
        return t

# Usage example:

dt = datetime.now()

res = date2str(dt, out_format=date)
assert type(res) == date

res = date2str(dt.date(), out_format=str)
assert type(res) == str
```

mypy gives error on the return statements (the TypeVar doesn't seem to work as I would have expected):

```
first return statement: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "date")
second return statement: error: Incompatible return value type (got "date", expected "str")
third return statement: error: Incompatible return value type (got "date", expected "str")
```

Any ideas?
Is there a better way to write this code with proper type annotation?

Comment: Why not separate functions?

Comment: basically to simplify usage: not worry about input type (=same function call), as long as output type is guaranteed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that mypy does not understand expressions of the form `some_type is str` or `type(some_value) is str`. You need to do either `issubclass(some_type, str)` or `isinstance(some_value, str)` instead.

That said, it would be more cleaner in this case to just make two different functions instead:

```py
def date_to_str(t: date) -> str:
    return t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def normalize_date(t: date) -> date:
    if isinstance(t, datetime):
        return t.date()
    return t
```

This ends up being fewer characters for your users to type since they don't need to keep including `out_format=date` or `out_format=str` everywhere. It's also less misleading: your original function doesn't actually always return a str, so calling it `date2str` is kind of confusing.

It would also probably be a good idea to just delete `normalize_date` entirely: datetime is a subclass of date, which means it's valid to use a datetime in any place that expects just a date. This means there really shouldn't be a need to explicitly convert a datetime into a date

For example, the following two prints would do the exact same thing (and would type check, according to mypy):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()
print(date_to_str(dt))
print(date_to_str(normalize_date(dt)))
```